# How to write files to a docker container's temporary directory?

Tags: docker

I am trying to write content(backup files) into a temporary directory inside a running Docker container.

Is there a way to create a temporary directory inside the container and write content to it?

Comment: Hey, I am not 100% understanding what you mean. If you do not mount a volume inside the container - all files and folders live as long as the docker-container itself, so are temporary

Comment: @RuthiRuth Thanks for responding. I have backup files in a file system and I am trying to copy them over to the container during runtime through PHP. For this reason, I want to create a temporary directory inside the container and have my backup files content written to it. Later I would be using these backup files inside the container to restore the databases using RESTORE DATABASE
FROM DISK = 'tempdirectorypath/dbname.bak'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind this folder to the docker container directly using [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).
As you do not want them changed I assume you could mount them as a read-only volume.
In that case you do not have to copy them around as you will have them accessible already in the container :)